# CentOS: Prevent the kernel from updating?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, update

I have installed a non-rpm custom kernel. I have a cron job which does `yum -y update` in the background. Is it sufficent to remove the kernel packages to prevent them from being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `exclude=kernel*` under `[main]` section in `/etc/yum.conf`.